# How do i ask a user to enter a file and let c++ open this file?

Tags: c++, file

Is it possible in simple c++ to ask an user to enter a path and manipulate this same file?
Does anyone know a website to get to know more about this? Google wasn't that easy this time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;


    char * b = 0;

    cin >> b;

    cout << b;

    const char * c = b;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (c);
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using C-strings instead of `std::string`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `char*` use a `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

std::string b;
```

As the code is, an attempt is being made write via a NULL pointer.

If not C++11, then you need to use `b.c_str()` to pass to `myfile.open()`:

```
myfile.open(b.c_str()); // Or ofstream myfile(b.c_str());
if (my_file.is_open())
{
    myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: You can just pass the string to `open()`, you know.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, only since C++11: [open()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)

Comment: Still not working.

Xcode says:

no viable conversion from 'string' to 'const char *'

Comment: Just `string b;` Does you compiler support C++11 features? If not, then use `myfile.open(b.c_str());`

Comment: Note that you don't need an explicit call to `close` method. The destructor will close the file when `myfile` variable goes out of scope (you do need to call `close` only if you want to close the file _before_ end of scope).